# Do we say "he has a stitch in his head"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I am not a stitching expert, but according to my research it seems like people stitch a wound differently from a split in clothes.

To stitch a split in clothes, we just need 1 long stitch and wind it around the split into a spiral shape.

Can we say "**my T-shirt has a stitch in its sleeve**"?

To stitch a wound, we may use many small stitches separately as the below picture.

[image]

Suppose that we stitch a wound just like stitching a clothes split.

Is it correct to say "**he has a stitch in his head**"?

Answer (score 1):

Almost right, but each time the thread goes between the two pieces of fabric or skin that we wish to join, it's a stitch. We use the number of stitches as an indicator of the severity of the wound. To describe your photograph, you would say

> He had to have 13 stitches in his head.

Comment: is it a long stitch with 13 rounds or are they 13 separated stitches?

Comment: 'A stitch' refers to each time the needle passes in and out of the fabric. In sewing, we don't speak of 'one stitch with 13 rounds', but '13 stitches'.

Answer (score 0):

When stitching 'suturing' a wound, the thread is usually carried through itself in a knot, each of these is one stitch.

[image]